# Section Scrolling with js

Tags: javascript

It is necessary to implement scrolling through the sections of the site. For example, when scrolling down, you need to scroll to the next section. And if we scroll up, then to the previous section.

```
  <body>
    <header></header>
    <div class="top"></div>
    <div class="mid"></div>
    <div class="bottom"></div>
    <footer></footer>
  </body>
```

UPD: i resolved it by finding this https://codepen.io/mystroken/pen/bKoebp

Comment: what exactly are you trying to ask its quite confusing, can you please elaborate it a little

Comment: As I understand from the little description of your question, I think you want to implement `scroll-snap` in your css.
[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-snap-type)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct implementation of section scrolling(step scrolling)

```
<div class="cachu__container">

  <!-- All sections are wrapped inside .cachu__sections  -->

  <div class="cachu__sections">
    <section class="cachu__section">Some section</section>
    <section class="cachu__section">Some section</section>
    <section class="cachu__section">Some section</section>
  </div>

  <!-- End of section  -->
  <!-- Navigation will be dynamically added here (via JavaScript) -->
</div>
```

JS

```
// Now let's turn on our slider!

// 1. Set some options.
// 2. Instantiate the Slider with the DOM Element instance of the wrapper.
// 3. Run the slider !!

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  
  const options = {};
  let slider = new  Cachu(document.querySelector('.cachu__container'), options);
  slider.run();
  
});
```

https://codepen.io/mystroken/pen/bKoebp

Answer (score 2):

no it is not neccessary to have scrolling only using section you could use divs as well to achieve the same. Here's an example for your understanding

```css
html{
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
.links{
  position: fixed;
  background: white;
}
div:not(.links){
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
#one{
  background: black;
}
#two{
  background: blue
}
#three{
  background: pink;
}
#four{
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="links">
  <a href="#one">one</a>
  <a href="#two">two</a>
  <a href="#three">three</a>
  <a href="#four">four</a>
</div>
<div id="one">
  
</div>
<div id="two">
  
</div>
<div id="three">
  
</div>
<div id="four">
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a example how you can scroll by JavaScript.
If you do not want smooth scroll, you 0 instead of 300 on button on-click.

```
button{cursor: pointer}
div{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}
#header{
  background: black;
}
#content{
  background: blue
}
#middle{
  background: pink;
}
#footer{
  background: green;
}
```

```
<div style="height:100px;position:fixed">
    <button onclick="scrollToSmoothly('header', 300)">header</button>
    <button onclick="scrollToSmoothly('content', 300)">content</button>
    <button onclick="scrollToSmoothly('middle', 300)">middle</button>
    <button onclick="scrollToSmoothly('footer', 300)">footer</button>
</div>
<div id="header">
  
</div>
<div id="content">
  
</div>
<div id="middle">
  
</div>
<div id="footer">
  
</div>
```

```
function scrollToSmoothly(id, time) {
    var pos = document.querySelector('#'+id).offsetTop;
    var currentPos = window.pageYOffset;
    var start = null;
    if(time == null) time = 500;
    pos = +pos, time = +time;
    window.requestAnimationFrame(function step(currentTime) {
        start = !start ? currentTime : start;
        var progress = currentTime - start;
        if (currentPos < pos) {
            window.scrollTo(0, ((pos - currentPos) * progress / time) + currentPos);
        } else {
            window.scrollTo(0, currentPos - ((currentPos - pos) * progress / time));
        }
        if (progress < time) {
            window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
        } else {
            window.scrollTo(0, pos);
        }
    });
}
```